# How to fill textarea and submit it from a text link from a div which we choose

Tags: javascript, html, textarea, chatbot

I want to ask, what if we press a button or link from a text that is in the div, then it is automatically submitted in the textarea.
The image below will help you understand my question
[image]

If we choose Finance, it means we type Finance also in the textarea and submit.
Can you help me?
Below is the code in my chat widget:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="end-convo"></div>
<!-- /.direct-chat-pane -->
</div>
<!-- /.card-body -->
<div class="card-footer">
  <form id="send_chat" method="post">
    <div class="input-group">
      <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Ketik sesuatu ..." class="form-control" required="" id="message"></textarea>
      <span class="input-group-append">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class='bx bx-send bx-sm'></i></button>
                    </span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- /.card-footer-->
</div>

<div class="d-none" id="user_chat">
  <div class="direct-chat-msg right  ml-4">
    <img class="direct-chat-img border-1 border-primary" src="<?php echo validate_image($_settings->info('user_avatar')) ?>" alt="message user image">

    <div class="direct-chat-text"></div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="d-none" id="bot_chat">
  <div class="direct-chat-msg mr-4">
    <img class="direct-chat-img border-1 border-primary" src="<?php echo validate_image($_settings->info('bot_avatar')) ?>" alt="message user image">

    <div class="direct-chat-text"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be nice if you provided the CSS too.

Comment: you can keep the selected value (finance/ registration) in a global state and bind it inside the textarea and do a click event automatically

Comment: would you like to give me some example code?